# Unable to split the values in jsonobject in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, split, hashmap

I'm new to groovy. I'm trying to split the values in json object in groovy but i cant seem to find a solution. Please find the sample code below

```
def inputFile = new File("C:\\graph.json")

                def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseFile(inputFile,'UTF-8')
                InputJSON.each{println it}
                def names = InputJSON.graph;
                def name
                for (int kk=0;kk<4;kk++)
                {
                name=names.JArray1[kk]

                run.put(name.runid, name.rundetails);
                println "test::"+name.runid+"--------------"+name.rundetails
                }
```

**graph.json**

```
    {
"graph": {
    "JArray1": [
        {
            "runid": 1,
            "rundetails":{


"01_Home":0.231,
"02_Login":0.561}
}
]
}
}
```

**name.rundetails** contains the below values

```
[01_Home:0.231, 02_Login:0.561]
```

I would like to split and add it as key and value in Hashmap like below format

```
Key:01_Home   Value:0.231
Key:02_Login   Value:0.561
```

How would i do that any advise on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need collection like:

```
[[Key:01_Home, Value:0.231], [Key:02_Login, Value:0.561]]
```

Then you may do:

```
println InputJSON.graph
                 .JArray1
                 .rundetails
                 .collectEntries{it}
                 .collect{[Key: it.key, Value: it.value]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import groovy.json.*

def inputFile = new StringReader('''
{
    "graph": {
        "JArray1": [{
                "runid": 1,
                "rundetails": {

                    "01_Home": 0.231,
                    "02_Login": 0.561
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
''')

def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)
json.graph.JArray1.each{run->
    println "runid   = ${run.runid}"
    // at this point `run.rundetails` is a map like you want
    println "details = ${run.rundetails}"    
}
```